# High Contrast underline issue with IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, accessibility, microsoft-edge, high-contrast

I encountered a glitch with the IE and Edge browsers. I have a list of tabs, and when a tab is selected, I add an underline to the selected tab to make it visible as selected. When you turn on high contrast mode, it still shows but with a different color than expected. This behavior is working fine in Chrome, but in case of IE and Edge, there is no underline when the high contrast mode is turned on.

I tried few fixes and researched a bit and found that adding border-right and border-left to the underline style makes it visible. But I need to provide a border-right and left width size in order for it to display, or else it displays the default width.

```
tabLineStyle: {
                height: "3px",
                width: "auto",
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                borderRight: "solid blue",
                borderLeft: "solid blue",
                borderRadius: "2px",
                opacity: 1,
                transition: "opacity 200ms;",
                marginTop: "3px",
            }
```

With the above code, I was able to display the underline in high contrast mode, but it is not visible for the whole width size of the line as we specified. I can hard code the width to make it visible in its entirety, but that might not be a right approach as it would affect other tabs with lesser or greater width size. 
My question is this: Is there any way to get the border-right width equal to its respective style width, or is there any other alternate method for this issue?

This is how it looks without the high contrast mode:

[image: Underline underlines the entire tab]

And this is how it looks in high contrast mode with the code I pasted in the question after I added the border left and right styles with no specific width:

[image: Underline is mostly invisible]

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special media query to specify a different color when in high-contrast mode:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* your new styling */
}
```

See: https://www.gwhitworth.com/blog/2017/04/how-to-use-ms-high-contrast/

Comment: Changing the color is not making it visible. After few different tries, i figured it only works when a border is added to the style. 
But i have two concerns

1) if i use border-right and left, i need to specify a certain width

2) if i use border or border-top i might not need to specify width but this affects the notmal view

Comment: Make the border the same dimension, but transparent for the normal case.

Answer (score 0):

If you like how your underline looks in Chrome, and you only need to change how it looks in Internet Explorer and Edge, use an outline to style it:

```
outline: "1px solid transparent"
outlineOffset: "-1px"
```

Your code includes a `height: "3px"`, so edit the values I used to your liking. An outline will not push other elements around on the page, because it's not included in the DOM. The `transparent` color becomes visible in Windows 10 High Contrast mode in Edge, IE, and Firefox. Chrome will not show it. The `outlineOffset` property will make the outline appear close to a solid underline. Again, edit the value until it has the appearance you're looking for.

Another advantage of using the `transparent` color instead of your own color is that the display color will change depending on which Windows 10 High Contrast setting the user selects.